# Why are there relative and absolut differences in performance among flow statements in CPython and pypy?

Tags: python, performance, loops, pypy

I'm reading the book *Learning python* (by Mark Lutz) and I use one of the programs shown in the book to measure the difference between flow statements. As I'm working in a project currently, I would like to know how faster **pypy** can be than my standard Python 3.7, which I guess is running in a C virtual machine. However, when I ran the program I was surprised to discover that there are hierarchical differences in relative and absolute performance among the flow statements depending on which implementation I chose to run. Does someone know why this happened?

Here is the code I used and the following two outputs:

```
# File timeseqs.py
"Test the relative speed of iteration tool alternatives."
import sys, timer # Import timer functions
reps = 10000
repslist = list(range(reps)) # Hoist out, list in both 2.X/3.X
def forLoop():
    res = []
    for x in repslist:
        res.append(abs(x))
    return res
def listComp():
    return [abs(x) for x in repslist]
def mapCall():
    return list(map(abs, repslist)) # Use list() here in 3.X only!
# return map(abs, repslist)
def genExpr():
    return list(abs(x) for x in repslist) # list() required to force results
def genFunc():
    def gen():
        for x in repslist:
            yield abs(x)
            return list(gen()) # list() required to force results
print(sys.version)
for test in (forLoop, listComp, mapCall, genExpr, genFunc):
    #(bestof, (total, result)) = timer.bestoftotal(5, 1000, test)
    print ('%-9s: %.5f => [%s...%s]' %(test.__name__, bestof, result[0], result[-1]))
```

Output in Python 3.7:

```
3.7.5 (default, Oct 25 2019, 15:51:11) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
forLoop  : 3.08886 => [0...9999]
listComp : 1.77405 => [0...9999]
mapCall  : 0.68121 => [0...9999]
genExpr  : 2.43599 => [0...9999]
```

Output in pypy3:

```
3.6.9 (5da45ced70e515f94686be0df47c59abd1348ebc, Oct 18 2019, 07:48:38)
[PyPy 7.2.0 with GCC 7.3.0]
forLoop  : 0.40884 => [0...9999]
listComp : 0.47015 => [0...9999]
mapCall  : 0.39428 => [0...9999]
genExpr  : 0.54222 => [0...9999]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you’re surprised by this, and what you were expecting instead? The two implementations differ and so, of course, does the performance of the various constructs they implement in various ways.

Comment: I thought that for loop, for instance, must always be slower than list comprehension. I thought this is a kind of characteristic of python, regardless of the implementation